# download files once uploaded via script

Tags: php, file-upload

I am creating a simple upload script but once I have uploaded the files If I link to the file with an  I get a server Forbidden error. I have set the permission to 750(have checked and the permissions are correct) so don't understand why this is happening....

Any help would be great, below is my upload script:

```
if($_POST["upload"]){

//gets current year for path
$year = date('Y');

//path to directory
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/uploads/' . $year . '/' . strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$_POST["username"])) . '/' . $_POST["month"];

//path to file
$target_path = $path . '/' . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

// $_FILES is the array auto filled when you upload a file and submit a form.
$file_name = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']; // file name
$file_tmp  = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']; // actual location
$file_size  = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size']; // file size
$file_type  = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type']; // mime type of file sent by browser. PHP doesn't check it.
$file_error  = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']; // any error!. get from here

if($file_error == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE){

    print "<div class='error'>Please select a file first</div>";

} elseif ($file_error == UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE) {

    print "<div class='error'>The file is too large</div>";

} elseif($file_error == UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL){

    print "<div class='error'>An error occured whilst trying to receive the file, please try again.</div>";

} elseif( !($file_type=="application/pdf")) {

        print "<div class='error'>Your File Type is: <b>". $file_type."</b> the file type must be <b>PDF</b></div>";

} elseif($file_error == 0){

    if(!is_dir($path)){

        mkdir($path, 0750, true);
    }

    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_path);

    chmod($target_path, 0750);


    print "<div class='success'>The file " . "<span class='filename'>" . basename($file_name) . "</span>" . " has been uploaded to <b>" . $_POST["username"] . "'s</b> folder</div>";

}
}
```

Comment: check the error log to see WHY you get forbidden.

Comment: I dont have an error_log by default, im hosting with 123reg, not sure if I can set one up will check now. Thanks

Comment: Ok so you now have to login to your control panel to view the log and the error_log is empty.... brilliant

Comment: set up the error_log but it isn't logging the forbidden error.. Last item is the page load itself then nothing about the Forbidden error

Answer (score 0):

Does Apache have access to the files? Try adding a chown line in with the chmod changes.

Comment: the file would've been created by apache in the first place. apache couldn't chown files to itself anyways. only root could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the file permission 750 or 777 won't let you download the file but 444 will. Not too sure why this is to be honest but it is working now.

Thanks for all your help guys.

Until next time!